# Масштабирование картинок

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

Всем привет, такая проблема - В мобильной версии нужно масштабировать изображения жестами, когда открывается фото в плагине. Но, так как в мобильной версии вообще отключено масштабирование (`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`), то и фото не увеличивается, если отключаю (`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`), то начинает все плыть. Можноли как-то средствами CSS или JS сделать ZOOM, если открыт тег img, или еще какие способы есть?

Плагин: Pretty Photo
CMS: Wordpress

Хороший пример того, что нужно - сайт [m.vk.com](http://m.vk.com)
А то есть, с мобильного устройства нельзя масштабировать страницу, а когда открываешь фото, то его можно увеличивать или уменьшать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: CSS Media Queries вам в помощь

Comment: @MasterAlex, интересно, а каким способом он мне поможет, не подскажите? У меня ведь проблема не в адаптивности, а в масштабирование картинок в адаптивном дизайне

Comment: дополните вопрос кодом: HTML-код функционала, код скрипта, css, название плагина. А из вашего объяснения мало что понятно, например фраза: `так как в мобильной версии вообще отключено масштабирование, то и фото не увеличивается, если отключаю, то начинает все плыть`. Что отключено? Что вы ещё отключаете? Ничего ведь непонятно из глаголов без существительных. Media Queries могут помочь с тем, чтобы задать размеры изображения, а можно и вообще другое изображение в мобильной версии.

Comment: Кстати говоря, фраза `Можноли как-то средствами CSS или JS прописать увеличение фото на тег img` тоже не особо объясняет то, что вам нужно. Во-первых, не написано по какому событию должно увеличиваться изображение, во-вторых, если событие есть, должен быть алгоритм увеличения, начальное состояние фото -> конечное состояние фото. В общем, ваш текст рождает больше вопросов, чем ответов, поэтому за час в вопросе полнейшая тишина.

Comment: @MasterAlex, подробнее описал проблему выше.

Comment: Картинку в iframe и все =) в iframe открывать страничку с нужными meta-атрибутами, по аналогии с yandex/google картами

Comment: @skywave, спасибо!